# Creating an updated dataframe from two lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two python lists in following form:

```
A = [(1,''), (1, 'toy'),(1,''), (1, 'boy'),(1,''), (1, 'GHI'),(1,''), (1, 'LMO'),(1,'')]
B = ['ToYS', 'bOYs', 'PQR']
```

(Note: A is a list of list. B is normal list.)

I have a code that looks like this:

```
match = [s for _, s in A if s.upper() or s.lower() in B]
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": match, "B": match})
```

however this one creates a df like this:

```
DF :
A     B
ABC   ABC
GHI   ghi
```

What I want is:

I want to create a pandas DF that will only contain element that are common from both the lists and the form will be:

```
DF :
A     B
toy   ToYS
boy   bOYs
```

**Please note there might be lower case- upper case and also white spaces. Also there might be some changes in words like boy and boys**

Comment: "_there might be some changes in words like boy and boys_". What kind of variations are you expecting?

Comment: @rodrigo I think its just singular plural. for instance 
A -> {'1','A boy in park'}
B -> {'Boys playing in park'}

Answer (score 0):

Your condition `if s.upper() or s.lower() in B` is always true because that is in fact

```
if (s.upper())   or   (s.lower() in B)
```

and `s.upper()` is a non-empty string so evaluated as `True`, then all rows matches

---

The `upper.lower` should apply to the elements of `B`, not of `A`, and you need a totally different approach to check and keep track of the B matching word

```
A = [(1, ''), (1, 'toy'), (1, ''), (1, 'boy'), (1, ''), (1, 'GHI'), (1, ''), (1, 'LMO'), (1, '')]
B = ['ToYs', 'bOYs', 'PQR']
match = []
for _, s in A:
    b_matches = [x for x in B if x.lower().startswith(s) or x.upper().startswith(s)]
    if s and b_matches:
        match.append((s, b_matches[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(match, columns=['A', 'B'])

print(df)

     A     B
0  toy  ToYs
1  boy  bOYs
```

Comment: This one returns an empty dataframe. sopmehow it does seem to work at b_macthes part

Comment: also @azro there are rows like this:
A- > toy in bag
B -> toys in bag

In this case i cannot use starts with. i need to use somethin glike contains.